# integral e with two variables

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

how are you? I have a problem with an integral. I get to a point where I don't know how to continue. I know there are several methods but I would like to follow this method.
i know that ∫dx e^a* a’ = e^a

so
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, dx\, x e^{-\frac{a}{2}x^2}
= -\frac{1}{a}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, dx\, (-ax) e^{-\frac{a}{2}x^2}
$$
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fwkm.png

And now I don't know whether to value x at infinity and minus infinity, or if before I would have had to substitute all that exponent with a single variable

Comment: Okay so you say that you don't know "whether to value x at infinity and minus infinity", and in the equations you have written the substitution expression 
$$
- \frac{1}{a} \left[ e^{- \frac{a}{2} x^2  } \right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}
$$
So surely, you know that 
$$
\left[F(x) \right]_a^b = F(b)-F(a)
$$, right? So what is $e^{-\infty}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

So you have
$$F(x)=\int x e^{\frac{-ax^2}{2}  }\, dx=-\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(a x^2\right)}}{a}+C$$

and
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } x e^{\frac{-ax^2}{2}} \, dx=\underset{M\to \infty }{\text{lim}}(F(M)-F(-M))$$

Edit

The result can be got without any calculation because $f(x)=x e^{\frac{-ax^2}{2}  }$ is an odd function, that is $f(-x)=-f(x)$, thus the integral is zero.